# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetcdf?

Tags: makefile, fortran, linker-errors, unresolved-external

First of all, this is my first question on here. If I make mistake, I'm sorry about that. **By the way I'm a newbie in Fortran**. I want to compile the "MMIF" model and the model has a compiler "makefile". I edited my "makefile" but I have an error message. When I used the `make` command, I'm getting this error:

```
...
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetcdf
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    makefile:62: recipe for target 'mmif' failed
    make: *** [mmif] Error 1
```

When I checked the location, I realised libnetcdf.a is missing. I don't know if it is needed in order to run the "makefile". Can you help me with this situation?

```
...
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a                
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.so      
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.so.6    
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.so.6.1.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf.settings 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf.so       
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf.so.13
...
```

---

Update 1

Thanks for helping and guiding me. I changed `-lnetcdf` to `-lnetcdff`. It works but I have a another problem now. I'm getting so many "undefined reference to..". Now, I'm trying to resolve these problems.

**Error Code**

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_text_':
(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `nc_put_att_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_text_a_':
(.text+0x193): undefined reference to `nc_put_att_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_int1_':
(.text+0x277): undefined reference to `nc_put_att_schar'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_int2_':
(.text+0x357): undefined reference to `nc_put_att_short'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_int_':
(.text+0x437): undefined reference to `nc_put_att_int'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_real_':
(.text+0x517): undefined reference to `nc_put_att_float'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_put_att_double_':
(.text+0x5f7): undefined reference to `nc_put_att_double'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_text_':
(.text+0x745): undefined reference to `nc_get_att_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_text_a_':
(.text+0x846): undefined reference to `nc_get_att_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_int1_':
(.text+0x916): undefined reference to `nc_get_att_schar'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_int2_':
(.text+0x9e6): undefined reference to `nc_get_att_short'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_int_':
(.text+0xab6): undefined reference to `nc_get_att_int'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_real_':
(.text+0xb86): undefined reference to `nc_get_att_float'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_attio.o): In function `nf_get_att_double_':
(.text+0xc56): undefined reference to `nc_get_att_double'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_create_':
(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `nc_create'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf__create_':
(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to `nc__create'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf__create_mp_':
(.text+0x292): undefined reference to `nc__create_mp'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_open_':
(.text+0x371): undefined reference to `nc_open'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf__open_':
(.text+0x45d): undefined reference to `nc__open'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf__open_mp_':
(.text+0x557): undefined reference to `nc__open_mp'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_open_mem_':
(.text+0x63c): undefined reference to `nc_open_mem'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_inq_path_':
(.text+0x78d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_path'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_set_fill_':
(.text+0x8ba): undefined reference to `nc_set_fill'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_set_default_format_':
(.text+0x910): undefined reference to `nc_set_default_format'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_delete_':
(.text+0xa3a): undefined reference to `nc_delete'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_delete_mp_':
(.text+0xb02): undefined reference to `nc_delete_mp'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_inq_base_pe_':
(.text+0xb60): undefined reference to `nc_inq_base_pe'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_redef_':
(.text+0x943): undefined reference to `nc_redef'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_enddef_':
(.text+0x953): undefined reference to `nc_enddef'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf__enddef_':
(.text+0x96f): undefined reference to `nc__enddef'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_sync_':
(.text+0x983): undefined reference to `nc_sync'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_abort_':
(.text+0x993): undefined reference to `nc_abort'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_close_':
(.text+0x9a3): undefined reference to `nc_close'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_control.o): In function `nf_set_base_pe_':
(.text+0xb35): undefined reference to `nc_set_base_pe'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_dim.o): In function `nf_def_dim_':
(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `nc_def_dim'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_dim.o): In function `nf_inq_dim_':
(.text+0x24c): undefined reference to `nc_inq_dim'
(.text+0x2a6): undefined reference to `nc_inq_dim'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_dim.o): In function `nf_inq_dimid_':
(.text+0x45d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_dimid'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_dim.o): In function `nf_inq_dimlen_':
(.text+0x4c9): undefined reference to `nc_inq_dimlen'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_dim.o): In function `nf_inq_dimname_':
(.text+0x63f): undefined reference to `nc_inq_dimname'
(.text+0x691): undefined reference to `nc_inq_dimname'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_dim.o): In function `nf_rename_dim_':
(.text+0x82e): undefined reference to `nc_rename_dim'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_genvar.o): In function `nf_def_var_':
(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `nc_def_var'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_varndims_':
(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_var_':
(.text+0x2f8): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x363): undefined reference to `nc_inq_var'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_vardimid_':
(.text+0x550): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x59a): undefined reference to `nc_inq_vardimid'
(.text+0x611): undefined reference to `nc_inq_vardimid'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_varid_':
(.text+0x6cf): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varid'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_varname_':
(.text+0x7e9): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varname'
(.text+0x831): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varname'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_vartype_':
(.text+0x955): undefined reference to `nc_inq_vartype'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_genvar.o): In function `nf_inq_varnatts_':
(.text+0x9a5): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varnatts'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_genvar.o): In function `nf_rename_var_':
(.text+0xa6e): undefined reference to `nc_rename_var'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_genvar.o): In function `nf_copy_var_':
(.text+0xaaa): undefined reference to `nc_copy_var'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_text_':
(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_text_a_':
(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x2c9): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_int1_':
(.text+0x35d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x459): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_schar'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_int2_':
(.text+0x4ed): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x5e9): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_short'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_int_':
(.text+0x67d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x779): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_int'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_real_':
(.text+0x80d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x909): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_float'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_double_':
(.text+0x99d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0xa99): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_double'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_':
(.text+0xb2d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0xc29): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_text_':
(.text+0xd31): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0xe3a): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_text_a_':
(.text+0xefd): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0xff9): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_int1_':
(.text+0x108d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x1189): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_schar'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_int2_':
(.text+0x121d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x1319): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_short'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_int_':
(.text+0x13ad): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x14a9): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_int'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_real_':
(.text+0x153d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x1639): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_float'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_double_':
(.text+0x16cd): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x17c9): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_double'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_':
(.text+0x185d): undefined reference to `nc_inq_varndims'
(.text+0x1959): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_text_':
(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_text_a_':
(.text+0x20e): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_int1_':
(.text+0x39e): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_schar'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_int2_':
(.text+0x52e): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_short'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_int_':
(.text+0x6be): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_int'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_real_':
(.text+0x84e): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_float'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_double_':
(.text+0x9de): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara_double'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_put_vara_':
(.text+0xb6e): undefined reference to `nc_put_vara'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_text_':
(.text+0xd72): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_text_a_':
(.text+0xf3e): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_text'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_int1_':
(.text+0x10ce): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_schar'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_int2_':
(.text+0x125e): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_short'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_int_':
(.text+0x13ee): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_int'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_real_':
(.text+0x157e): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_float'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_double_':
(.text+0x170e): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_double'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.a(nf_varaio.o): In function `nf_get_vara_':
(.text+0x189e): undefined reference to `nc_get_vara'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:62: recipe for target 'mmif' failed
make: *** [mmif] Error 1
```

### makefile

```
#
# Makefile for MMIF VERSION 3.4.1 2019-03-11
#
# Edit this file to un-comment the section for your compiler.  
# You will also need to edit the line that specifies where to find the 
# NetCDF libraries, which must be compiled by the same compiler.
# The directory "netcdf.4.1.1-mingw" is used to commpile under MS Windows.
# It was compiled using MinGW version 20110802, see http://www.mingw.org, 
# and the script compile_netcdf_mingw.sh.
#
# PGI started linking with the OpenMP library by default in their 11.0 release,
# so that users would be able to use CPU binding even with serial code.  
# Adding "-mp=nonuma -nomp" to FFLAGS fixes "can't find libnuma.so" problems.

# PGI Fortran:
# FC = pgf90
# FFLAGS = -g -fast -Mlfs           # -Mlfs is default on for x86_64
# FFLAGS += -Mbounds              # for bounds checking/debugging
# FFLAGS += -Bstatic_pgi            # to use static PGI libraries
# FFLAGS += -Bstatic                # to use static netCDF libraries
# FFLAGS += -mp=nonuma -nomp        # fix for "can't find libnuma.so"
# NETCDF = /usr/local/src/netcdf-4.1.1.pgi

# GNU gfortran (Windows or Linux, just set NETCDF below correctly)
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -g -Wall
FFLAGS += -fbounds-check          # for bounds checking/debugging
FFLAGS += -static                 # to use static libraries
NETCDF = /usr

# Intel Fortran:
#FC = ifort
#FFLAGS = -O2 -align dcommons -ipo
#FFLAGS += -static                 # to use static libraries
#NETCDF = /path/to/netcdf-4.1.1.ifort

# NETCDF values that are the same for all compilers
INCL = -I$(NETCDF)/include
LIBS = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lnetcdff

PROGRAM = mmif

TODAY   = 2019-03-11
VERSION = 3.4.1
NEWTAG  = 3.4.1 2019-03-11
OLDTAG  = 3.4.1 2019-03-01

MODULES = met_fields.f90 functions.f90 module_llxy.f90 wrf_netcdf.f90     \
    parse_control.f90

SOURCES = aggregate.f90 avg_zface.f90 cloud_cover.f90 interpolate.f90     \
    landuse.f90 mmif.f90 output_aercoare.f90 output_aermet.f90        \
    output_calmet.f90 output_onsite.f90 output_scichem.f90            \
    pasquill_gifford.f90 pbl_height.f90 read_mm5.f90 read_wrf.f90     \
    sfc_layer.f90 timesubs.f90 

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.f90=.o)
MODOBJS = $(MODULES:.f90=.o)
MODMODS = $(MODULES:.f90=.mod)

$(PROGRAM): $(MODOBJS) $(OBJECTS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(MODOBJS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o $@

%.o : %.f90 
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(INCL) -c $< -o $@

install: $(PROGRAM)
    cp $(PROGRAM) /usr/local/bin

update_version: 
    sed -i "s|VERSION $(OLDTAG)|VERSION $(NEWTAG)|g" \
        *.f90 README.txt makefile makefile.windows mmif_change_log.txt

distro: 
    mmif --sample > mmif.inp
    unix2dos *.f90 *.sh makefile.windows old_compile.bat README*.txt mmif.inp
    zip -j MMIFv$(VERSION)_$(TODAY).zip \
        mmif.exe mmif mmif.inp *.f90 *.sh makefile \
        makefile.windows old_compile.bat README*.txt \
        MMIFv$(VERSION)_Users_Manual.pdf \
        mmif_change_log.txt test_problems/*/*.inp
    dos2unix *.f90

test_pkg: 
    zip -r MMIFv$(VERSION)_test_problems.zip \
        test_problems -x \*/wrf/\* \*/mm5/\*

test_pkg_mm5+wrf:
    zip -r MMIF_test_problems_mm5+wrf.zip \
        test_problems/wrf \
        test_problems/mm5

clean:
    rm $(MODMODS) $(MODOBJS) $(OBJECTS) $(PROGRAM)
```

**Library**

```
-------
This netCDF 4.6.0 has been built with the following features: 

  --cc        -> /usr/bin/cc
  --cflags    -> -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/hdf5/serial
  --libs      -> -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial -lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lpthread -lsz -lz -ldl -lm -lcurl

  --has-c++   -> no
  --cxx       -> 

  --has-c++4  -> no
  --cxx4      -> 

  --has-fortran-> yes
  --fc        -> gfortran
  --fflags    -> -I/usr/include
  --flibs     -> -L/usr/lib -lnetcdff -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -lnetcdf -lnetcdf
  --has-f90   -> no
  --has-f03   -> yes

  --has-dap   -> yes
  --has-dap2  -> yes
  --has-dap4  -> yes
  --has-nc2   -> yes
  --has-nc4   -> yes
  --has-hdf5  -> yes
  --has-hdf4  -> no
  --has-logging-> no
  --has-pnetcdf-> no
  --has-szlib -> no
  --has-cdf5 -> no
  --has-parallel-> no

  --prefix    -> /usr
  --includedir-> /usr/include
  --libdir    -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  --version   -> netCDF 4.6.0
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You will have to give us much more information, see also [ask] and [mcve]. Namely, we need to know where you libraries are located, how did you install them, what environment variables like `LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are in effect and the content of your Makefile. You must tell us how exactly you edited your Makefile and how exactly it looks now. Please do also read this specific information https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unresolved-external/info

Comment: Here's a wild guess - try changing `-lnetcdf` to `-lnetcdff` and see how you get on.

Comment: If you're building a Fortran program you'll need both `-lnetcdf` and `-lnetcdff`. Documentation includes, hopefully, mention of `nf-config`.

Comment: if I use this `LIBS = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lnetcdff -lnetcdf`, I'm getting this error  `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetcdf`.   I'm so confused. what should ı do now? should I clean all netcdf, maybe should I use another version?

Comment: The `-lnetcdf` issue is as you had before, so not too surprising that it still fails.  However, you can use the utility `nf-config --flibs` to get details of the flags required to link a Fortran program against NetCDF.  Note the `--libs` and `--flibs` in the output you present which have directories other than the single `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.